# Defining Variables Outside the Draw Loop in p5 When Using node.js

Tags: node.js, p5.js

I've been able to get a node.js server up and running (and port forwarded), but I can't seem to figure out how to define variables outside the draw loop without the client's code either crashing or not working properly.

When I define it inside the draw loop, everything loads and works fine, but the variable keeps getting redefined, which means I can't change it.

When I define it outside the draw loop, the code stops (inside the draw loop) where I try using that variable. The draw loop is then never called again.

Working code:

```
var socket;

var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var targetHost = '75.38.209.199';
var port = 25565;
httpProxy.createProxyServer({target:'http://' + targetHost + ':' + port}).listen(port);

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 600);
  socket = io.connect('');
}
function draw() {
  var x = 20;
  background(50);
  fill(255);
  text(x, 300, 300);
  x++;
}
```

If you were to try this, then you'd notice that x always stays at 20.
So, I tried defining the variable outside the loop:

```
var socket;

var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var targetHost = '75.38.209.199';
var port = 25565;
httpProxy.createProxyServer({target:'http://' + targetHost + ':' + port}).listen(port);

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 600);
  socket = io.connect('');
}
var x = 20;
function draw() {
  background(50);
  fill(255);
  text(x, 300, 300);
  x++;
}
```

When I run it though, the text is not even displayed (as it has failed to run), and the draw loop is only called once.

When I run the second code, the Chrome JavaScript console returns this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
>       at p5.Renderer2D.text (p5.js:13283)
>       at p5.text (p5.js:26924)
>       at draw (sketch.js:34)
>       at p5.redraw (p5.js:14256)
>       at p5. (p5.js:9143)
>       at p5. (p5.js:9049)
>       at new p5 (p5.js:9320)
>       at _globalInit (p5.js:5602)

If you need the server code or the client's HTML, I will provide it if asked. Help?

EDIT: Instance mode code

```
var socket;
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var targetHost = '75.38.209.199';
var port = 25565;
httpProxy.createProxyServer({target:'http://' + targetHost + ':' + port}).listen(port);

var s = function( sketch ) {
  var x = 100;
  var y = 100;
  sketch.setup = function() {
    sketch.createCanvas(200, 200);
  };
  sketch.draw = function() {
    sketch.background(0);
    sketch.fill(255);
    sketch.rect(x,y,50,50);
  };
};
var myp5 = new p5(s);
```

Comment: Your problem is not related to the socket stuff, so you should post a [mcve] without any of that stuff. What happens when you use instance mode instead of global mode?

Comment: There's no error, but the canvas is not displayed. Not sure if I'm doing it right? var socket;

var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var targetHost = '75.38.209.199';
var port = 25565;
httpProxy.createProxyServer({target:'http://' + targetHost + ':' + port}).listen(port);

var s = function( sketch ) {

  var x = 100; 
  var y = 100;

  sketch.setup = function() {
    sketch.createCanvas(200, 200);
  };

  sketch.draw = function() {
    sketch.background(0);
    sketch.fill(255);
    sketch.rect(x,y,50,50);
  };
};

var myp5 = new p5(s);

Comment: Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: What happened when you used instance mode instead of global mode?

Comment: I already said what - there was no longer an error, but the canvas was not being displayed at all - only a blank webpage.

Comment: Nothing you posted is instance mode. I believe you have to use instance mode with node.js. Instance mode is a very specific feature with different syntax than you've posted.

Comment: I left a comment with the code; I'll edit the original post now. EDIT: Done!

Comment: Your code works fine for me if I take out the socket stuff. So I'm guessing the problem is something with the `createProxyServer` line.

Comment: Hm... not sure? The server and everything else works fine without the variable thing...

Comment: On the original one (with x being defined inside the draw loop), I found I can do this: var x = 20 + frameCount; In this case, it works. But, I still need to be able to define it outside to loop for other cases, like player positions...